# Is there any side-effect of NVT when I use telnet to communicate with a http server?

Tags: http, network-protocols, telnet

I'm studying HTTP Protocol and have tried to use telnet to communicate with a http server. I didn't think too much about it at first, but when I knew more about it I was confused by NVT used by telnet.

I have searched many references and it seems that HTTP Protocol doesn't use NVT. That's the problem. Telnet transfroms my input into NVT ASCII but http server doesn't know that. I think the reason why telnet can communicate with http server properly is because NVT ASCII equals ASCII when sending data. I'm wondering if NVT changed end-of-line to CR but not CRLF, could telnet still communicate with http server correctly.

I want to know whether I'm right or not. If I was right, is there any side-effect of NVT when I use telnet to do that and why? If I was wrong, waht's the reason for telnet to do that properly?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You should install Wireshark, which is a network sniffer that allows you to see every bit of data (literally and figuratively) running across your interface. This will allow you to inspect your data on the packet level, meaning you can see exactly what bytes are being issued for CR/CRLF. It (or another, similar utility like tcpdump) is essential to diagnosing and blackboxing strange low-level network behavior that doesn't come readily answerable in documentation.